# How to set the name to a Table which the user entered in Edit Text in Android

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android. In my project, I want to set the name of the Table as what the user entered in the edit text from the other **Activity**. Can someone help me about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain in detail to get answer

Comment: what do you refer to as Table here? sqlite?

Comment: post some code that refer to ur table and edit text

Comment: Your question is not that clear, please explain more fully and post some code.

Comment: I already got the value of my edittext, my only problem is , i do not know how to pass that value to another class, and set it as the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to retrieve the text from the edittext and then convert it to a string.. and then attach it to the table creation statement and done.

Also to pass this information from one activity to another, you'd pass the table name in and intent and then consume the data in the intent and use it for the creation statement as mentioned above.

Comment: i already converted my editText .here's the code: `View etSubjCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSub); String myEditText1 = ((TextView) etSubjCode).getText().toString();`                    What I want to happen is to set the myEditText1 as the table name and i have a class called ClassDb where my database is created. I have tried using intent and bundle but i got error. Can someone tell me the correct code? Thank You. :)

Comment: Everytime i use intent in a class where i created my database, i got error.